# What is "edge progression" in some old literature on graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I was reading [*A characterization of the minimum cycle mean in a digraph*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X78900110?via%3Dihub) by Richard M. Karp (1978). In this paper, the term "edge progression" is used to mean something close to "walk" or "trail" or "path". But I am not sure which one (or maybe none of them). Can anyone confirm the usage of the term "edge progression"?

Below is a screenshot of the paragraphs where the term first appears.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one instance in the paper where an edge progression is constructed:

> Let $C$ be a cycle of weight $0$, and let $w$ be a vertex in $C$. Let $P(w)$ be a path of weight $\pi(w)$ from $x$ to $w$. Then $P(w)$, followed by any number of repetitions of $C$, is also a minimum-weight edge progression from $x$ to $w$.

This tells us that an edge progression is a walk or trail in the directed graph (depending on how you use those terms): it obeys the edge orientations (because paths and cycles do this) but it may repeat vertices and edges.